# $composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0" ERROR

Tags: php, login, powershell, terminal, composer

estoy trabajando en un login con Google y PHP. Necesito ejecutar el codigo $composer require google/apiclient:"^2.0"  pero hay problemas.

He instalado composer correctamente manualmente, pero a la hora de abrir la terminal con powershell(Visual studio) y ejecutar el codigo me tira el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero se que composer esta correctamente instalado, asi que creo que debe ser problema de visual studio o la terminal. Alguna idea de como solucionar esto? Gracias por la atencion.

He probado ejecutar ese codigo (sin el signo pesos) en el cmd, no funciona pero me marca lo siguiente, que es interesante:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cúal es el motivo por el que agregas el signo $ a composer?

Comment: @JulioGuerrero Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Estoy siguiendo un tutorial que da dicho código, lo coloca en una terminal y todo parece andar perfectamente. Y aunque no lo pusiere, sigue tirando error. Mas que nada en visual, porque en el cmd no tira error,solo se interrumpe la descarga por falta de archivos, al menos eso dice.

Comment: @MaveyDraws puede ser un error, puede ser que este en linux o macOS ... windows es otra cosa, te dejo una respuesta.

Comment: El signo `$` lo pone la consola eventualmente, no tú. El mensaje de error te dice que no tienes `git` en el directorio, puede ser ese el problema, necesita `git` para descargar o actualizar los archivos.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Voy a intentar descargar git, voy a comentar como salga. Muchas gracias

Comment: no necesitas descargar git para eso

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 revisa el mensaje de error. Es evidente que un archivo de ese proyecto está requiriendo `git` para descargar ciertos archivos. El mensaje es bastante claro, va a necesitar `git`.

Comment: @A.Cedano , el error que mencionas no tiene nada que ver con la correcta ejecucion del comando ... inicial, que en el camino le salga  otros 40 errores por dependencias es otro tema y debe ser una sola pregunta por post.

Comment: incluso Antes de instalar git deberia resolver el warning de la extension php ... cosa que no tiene nada que ver con que si sabe ejecutar los comando de composer

Answer (score 1):

estoy casi seguro de que el comando correcto es como lo indica la [documentación](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client#composer):

```
composer require google/apiclient:^2.15.0
```

Sin el caracter "$" que estas colocando delante, para validar que todo esta bien puede ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
composer --version
```

Ejemplo output:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si crees que el composer no esta actualizado puedes ejecutar:

```
composer self-update
```

por que aparece el caracter "$", esto se trata del caracter de comando que suelen mostrar algunas consolas/terminales: `usuario@mi-pc:~$` o `usuario@mi-pc:/$`

Comment: Muy bien, muchas gracias. Cuando se habla de ejecutar el comando, es el terminal cmd de visual studio, powershell o el mismo cmd?

Comment: en teoria al final los 3 hacen lo mismo: cmd es el mas viejo y visual studio ejecuta una instancia de powershell dentro de el ... asique es lo mismo que ir a power shell y abrirlo como programa

Comment: la diferencia entre powershell y cmd, es que powershell es mas nuevo y tiene mayor control sobre las herramientas que puede ejecutar.

Comment: bueno gracias, voy a intentar lo que me dices e instalar git, voy a comentar lo que pase

Comment: Antes de instalar git fijate que hayas resuelto el warning de la extension...

Comment: no entendi el warning, dice que faltan unos archivos, se referira al php.ini?

Comment: te lo explico asi; tu servidor si mas no me equivoco debe ser apache; y al apache viene o le instalas la version de php (esto se le dice stack, empaquetado); sucede que php es como un programa que le puedes agregar extensiones... hay muchas extensiones y algunas librerias de que se instalan en composer requieren extensiones especificas instaladas en php, una de esas extensiones es la que te esta pidiendo en el mensaje y te sale el warning... eso es otro problema y es otro tema aparte, que deberias resolver en otro post.

Comment: bueno gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder mis dudas, voy a probar lo que me han dicho para ver que pasa, gracias.

Answer (score -1):

tuve una solucion a mi problema, puedo decir que en la consola de git, el codigo se ejecuto. Puse en git los comandos de arriba y me anduvo bien. Se descargo el google api client aunque me marca algunas fallas, pero se instalo igualmente. Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Comment: Esto.. no es una respuesta.. si la respuesta que esta te sirvio, aceptala... si no, especifica porque no sirvio, y como lo resolviste...